# Java 8 / Jboss EAP 6.4.2 - Occassional java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory while connecting to a SOAP WS

Tags: java-8, jboss-eap-6

Since the migration to Java 8 we are facing a problem while connecting to SOAP webservice. The connection works fine sometimes(actually rarely) but most of the times we get
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory` The transient nature of this issue is another concern. The memory availability on the application server looks ok.

- Java8
- Jboss EAP 6.4.2

Most of the other related questions on SO show that people faced this issue after upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11, etc. but not while using Java 8.
Any hints about the possible causes and solution suggestions?

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:350)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:446)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:478)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.createPort(ProviderImpl.java:558)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:345)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory from [Module "deployment.ear.ejb-jboss.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:196) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:361) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:341)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:339)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:339)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:240)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:493)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:348)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory from [Module "deployment.ear.ejb-jboss.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:211) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:510) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:194) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    ... 88 more
```